# How to pass result from onpostexecute method to another activity using intent

Tags: java, android, oncreate

How i pass the result obtained from onpostexecute method to another activity or into oncreate method using intent

Comment: Send a bundle of data with the intent, then in the new Activity catch it by overriding the onNewIntent() method.

Comment: Please don't just open another question. Instead edit your previous question and provide the additional information requested by the users trying to help you

Comment: Check this link to get result to main activity. Once you got the result, you can pass it to next activity: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onPostExecute(String result){

     Intent intent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("YourData", result);
     StartActivity(intent)

}
```

and get it in another activity via `getIntent()`

Comment: @user3431956 Please do not edit someone's answer and add code. Instead, edit your _question_.